# How to unload or reload a SCSS for an Angular 11 component?

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

As far as I understood, Angular doesn't remove any `<styles>` on component destruction. But is there a way to reload a SCSS on dynamic component creation?

What I want to achieve? I have a container that shall show different components of the same type. The components need to have the same class-name `scoreboardContent`:

```
Container
---------
    Cycle1  click -> load TextComponent with style#1
            click -> load TextComponent with style#2
            click -> load TextComponent with style#3

    Cycle1  click -> load TextComponent with style#1    -> PROBLEM: it shows CSS of style#3
            click -> load TextComponent with style#2    -> PROBLEM: it shows CSS of style#3
```

On each click a `TextComponent`is created dynamically with the typical "Angular way", like:

```
...
container.clear();
const cfr = AppInjector.get(ComponentFactoryResolver);
const factory = cfr.resolveComponentFactory(template);
this.componentRef = container.createComponent(factory);

container.insert(this.componentRef.hostView);
...
```

This works fine for the first cycle. But in second cycle always shows the CSS of `style#3`. This is obvious because in `<head>` exists now styles for `style#1`,`style#2` and `style#3`, and they overwrite each other.

To resolve this issue, I try to remove the unused `style` from the `<head>` with something like that:

```
var styles = document.getElementsByTagName('style');

for (var i = 0, max = styles.length; i < max; i++) {
    if (/scoreboardContent/.test(styles[i]?.innerHTML)) {
        styles[i].parentNode.removeChild(styles[i]);
    }
}
```

That also works for the first cycle, but later the `style` is not created anymore. In other words: there is not `scoreboardContent` class available anymore. So my questions are now:

- Why doesn't Angular create a new `style` in second cycle? I expected that dynamically created components will also create the styles? Is there a way to force it?
- Is there maybe a different approach to achieve the desired behaviour? (I saw en example to load a CSS-file via a service, but this is not applicable because SCSS is necessary to be used)

Thx for any hints and solutions!

Comment: have you considered using ngStyle or ngClass directive ?

Comment: @rahultiwari but where should I apply a ngClass? I'm just using the `styleUrls` to load the scss

Comment: you can use ngClass on the conditions where you want to change the style https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/

Comment: @rahultiwari :-) the problem is not the ngClass. The `TextComponent` is loaded dynamically and such a component has its own SCSS file. So it is not an issue on applying a class. It's more a problem that Angular doesn't seem to handle the `styleUrl` on dynamic component creation the second time.